# Trying to understand Microchip PIC16LF15344 peripheral pin selection for I2C

Tags: c, embedded, microcontroller, pic, microchip

I have been reviewing the `Microchip PIC16LF15344` datasheet for peripheral pin selection, and either I am reading it incorrectly or it appears to have errors and inconsistencies in the document.  I would like to know if anyone else has used this device and can confirm my interpretation.

I'm trying to write code for a `PIC16LF15344` to make use of the `I2C` interface. I have managed to write `I2C` code for a `PIC16LF1822` that works fine, but I have so far been unable to get this to work on the `PIC16LF15344`, and there is some confusing documentation in the data sheet that I would like to get cleared up.

Here is a reference to the [datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/40001889a.pdf).

The `pinout` descriptions for the `PIC16LF15344` shows that the `I2C SDA` function can be allocated to `RC1` or `RB6`. Likewise, `I2C SCL` may be allocated to `RC0` or `RB4`. But there is a note in `Section 15.3 Bidirectional Pins` as follows.

> The `I2C SCLx` and `SDAx` functions can be remapped through `PPS`. However, only the `RB1`, `RB2`, `RC3`, and `RC4` pints have the `I2C` and `SMBus` specific input buffers implemented (`I2C` mode disables `INLVL` and sets thresholds that are specific for `I2C`). If the `SCLx` or `SDAx` functions are mapped to some other pin (other than `RB1`, `RB2`, `RC3`, or `RC4`), the general purpose `TTL` or `ST` input buffers (as configured based on `INLVL` register setting) will be used instead. In most applications, it is therefore recommended only to map the `SCLx` and `SDAx` pin functions to the `RB1`, `RB2`, `RC3` or `RC4` pins.

The problem is not only does the note appear to conflict with the descriptions in the pin allocation tables, it also references pins `RB1` and `RB2`, which don't appear anywhere in the pin allocation tables, i.e., they don't appear to exist for this `PIC`. I see similar footnote references to `RB1` and `RB2`, but they are not documented anywhere in the body of the document or the tables.

Certainly this must be a documentation error, but I can find no current errata on the `PIC16LF15324/44` datasheet to correct this. Am I reading this right?

I have tried configuring `SCL` and `SDA` with `PPS` to pins `RC0` and `RC1`, since that is how they are wired on my `PCB`, but I can't get the `I2C` working yet using essentially the same software that I was using for the `PIC16LF1822`. The `PPS` default for `EUSART TX2` and `RX2` are `RC0` and `RC1`. Does that mean I need to use `TX2CKPPS` and `RX2DTPPS` to move the `EUSART` assignments elsewhere before using `SSP1CLKPPS` and `SSP1DATPPS` to assign `SCL` and `SDA` to `RC0` and `RC1`?

I will be investigating other potential problems with my `PCB`, but I want to get this straightened out before I submit another `PCB` for fab. I need to make some changes anyway, so I might just connect `SCL` and `SDA` to their `PPS` defaults in the next version and try again.

Here is the initialization code:

```
OSCFRQbits.HFFRQ = 0b011; // Set internal HF oscillator frequency to 8 MHz
WPUA   = 0b00111111;    // Enable all weak pull-up resistors on port A
WPUB   = 0b11110000;    // Enable all weak pull-up resistors on port B
WPUC   = 0b11111100;    // Enable all weak pull-up resistors on port C except
                        //    RC0 and RC1 to be used as I2C SCL and SDA
TRISA  = 0b00110000;    // Set RA4 and RA5 as inputs
ANSELA = 0b00110000;    // Set RA4 and RA5 to analog
TRISB  = 0b00110000;    // Set RB6 and RB7 as inputs
ANSELB = 0b11000000;    // Set RB6 and RB7 as analog
TRISC  = 0b11111011;    // Set RC0, RC1, RC3, RC4, RC5, RC6, and RC7 as inputs
ANSELC = 0b11111000;    // Set RC3, RC4, RC5, RC6, and RC7 as analog
TX2CKPPS   = 0b01100;   // Use RB4 for TX2
RX2DTPPS   = 0b01110;   // Use RB6 for RX2
SSP1CLKPPS = 0b10000;   // Use RC0 as SCL
SSP1DATPPS = 0b10001;   // Use RC1 as SDA
SSP1CON1 = 0b00100110;  // SSPEN enabled, WCOL no collision, SSPOV no overflow,
                        // CKP low hold, SSPM I2C slave 7-bit

SSP1CON2 = 0b00000000;  // ACKSTAT received, RCEN disabled, RSEN disabled, 
                        // ACKEN disabled, ACKDT acknowledge, SEN disabled, 
                        // GCEN disabled, PEN disabled

SSP1CON3 = 0b00000000;  // BOEN disabled, AHEN disabled, SBCDE disabled, 
                        // SDAHT 100 ns hold, ACKTIM ackseq, DHEN disabled, 
                        // PCIE disabled, SCIE disabled

SSP1STAT = 0x00;
SSP1BUF  = 0x00;
SSP1MSK  = 0xff;
SSP1ADD  = I2C_SLAVE_ADDR << 1;
PIR3bits.SSP1IF = 0;    // Clear the SSP Interrupt flag
PIE3bits.SSP1IE = 1;    // Enable SSP Interrupts
INTCONbits.GIE = 1;     // Enable global interrupts
INTCONbits.PEIE = 1;    // Enable peripheral interrupts
```

Comment: I used the PPS on the PIC16F15324 and it works fine(maybe a little bit tricky). Could you show your code?

Comment: Initialization code added as requested.

Comment: Updated my answer with better PPS init code.

Answer (score 3):

You likely have several issues to deal with.

All of the default `I2C` pins also have analog functionality too. Be sure that the `ANSB` or `ANSC` bits that are associated with the `I2C` pins are setup for digital operation.

While the power on reset selects the data sheet defaults for the `I2C` input pin assignments the `I2C` outputs by default are not assigned to any `GPIO` pin. You will need to place the `I2C` outputs for `SCL` and `SDA` in the correct `PPS` mapping registers.

Note that regardless of the `I2C` master or slave implementation both the input and output functions should be mapped to the same pin.

It would help to edit your question and post the code that you use to initialize the `I2C` pins and `PPS` mapping registers.

```
/*
 * File:   main.c
 *                             PIC16LF15354
 *                   +-------------:_:-------------+
 * 10K Pull-Up ->  1 : RE3/MCLR   ANB7/RX2/PGD/RB7 : 28 <> 
 *             <>  2 : RA0/ANA0   ANB6/TX2/PGC/RB6 : 27 <> RX2
 *             <>  3 : RA1/ANA1           ANB5/RB5 : 26 <>
 *             <>  4 : RA2/ANA2           ANB4/RB4 : 25 <> TX2
 *             <>  5 : RA3/ANA3           ANB3/RB3 : 24 <>
 *             <>  6 : RA4/ANA4      ANB2/SDA2/RB2 : 23 <>
 *             <>  7 : RA5/ANA5      ANB1/SCL2/RB1 : 22 <>
 *         GND ->  8 : VSS                ANB0/RB0 : 21 <>
 *             <>  9 : RA7/OSC1/ANA7           VDD : 20 <- 3v3
 *             <> 10 : RA6/OSC2/ANA6           VSS : 19 <- GND
 *        SCL1 <> 11 : RC0/ANC0       ANC7/RX1/RC7 : 18 <>
 *        SDA1 <> 12 : RC1/ANC1       ANC6/TX1/RC6 : 17 <>
 *             <> 13 : RC2/ANC2           ANC5/RC5 : 16 <> 
 *             <> 14 : RC3/SCL1/ANC3 ANC4/SDA1/RC4 : 15 <>
 *                   +-----------------------------:
 *                               DIP-28
 *
 * Created on January 4, 2019, 6:20 PM
 */


// PIC16LF15354 Configuration Bit Settings
#pragma config FEXTOSC = OFF    // External Oscillator mode selection bits (Oscillator not enabled)
#pragma config RSTOSC = HFINT32 // Power-up default value for COSC bits (HFINTOSC with OSCFRQ= 32 MHz and CDIV = 1:1)
#pragma config CLKOUTEN = OFF   // Clock Out Enable bit (CLKOUT function is disabled; i/o or oscillator function on OSC2)
#pragma config CSWEN = ON       // Clock Switch Enable bit (Writing to NOSC and NDIV is allowed)
#pragma config FCMEN = OFF      // Fail-Safe Clock Monitor Enable bit (FSCM timer disabled)
#pragma config MCLRE = ON       // Master Clear Enable bit (MCLR pin is Master Clear function)
#pragma config PWRTE = OFF      // Power-up Timer Enable bit (PWRT disabled)
#pragma config LPBOREN = OFF    // Low-Power BOR enable bit (ULPBOR disabled)
#pragma config BOREN = OFF      // Brown-out reset enable bits (Brown-out reset disabled)
#pragma config BORV = LO        // Brown-out Reset Voltage Selection (Brown-out Reset Voltage (VBOR) set to 1.9V on LF, and 2.45V on F Devices)
#pragma config ZCD = OFF        // Zero-cross detect disable (Zero-cross detect circuit is disabled at POR.)
#pragma config PPS1WAY = OFF    // Peripheral Pin Select one-way control (The PPSLOCK bit can be set and cleared repeatedly by software)
#pragma config STVREN = ON      // Stack Overflow/Underflow Reset Enable bit (Stack Overflow or Underflow will cause a reset)
#pragma config WDTCPS = WDTCPS_31// WDT Period Select bits (Divider ratio 1:65536; software control of WDTPS)
#pragma config WDTE = SWDTEN    // WDT operating mode (WDT enabled/disabled by SWDTEN bit in WDTCON0)
#pragma config WDTCWS = WDTCWS_7// WDT Window Select bits (window always open (100%); software control; keyed access not required)
#pragma config WDTCCS = SC      // WDT input clock selector (Software Control)
#pragma config BBSIZE = BB512   // Boot Block Size Selection bits (512 words boot block size)
#pragma config BBEN = OFF       // Boot Block Enable bit (Boot Block disabled)
#pragma config SAFEN = OFF      // SAF Enable bit (SAF disabled)
#pragma config WRTAPP = OFF     // Application Block Write Protection bit (Application Block not write protected)
#pragma config WRTB = OFF       // Boot Block Write Protection bit (Boot Block not write protected)
#pragma config WRTC = OFF       // Configuration Register Write Protection bit (Configuration Register not write protected)
#pragma config WRTSAF = OFF     // Storage Area Flash Write Protection bit (SAF not write protected)
#pragma config LVP = OFF        // Low Voltage Programming Enable bit (High Voltage on MCLR/Vpp must be used for programming)
#pragma config CP = OFF         // UserNVM Program memory code protection bit (UserNVM code protection disabled)

#include <xc.h>

#define I2C_SLAVE_ADDR 0x00

void main(void) 
{
    WPUA   = 0b00111111;    // Enable all weak pull-up resistors on port A
    WPUB   = 0b11110000;    // Enable all weak pull-up resistors on port B
    WPUC   = 0b11111100;    // Enable all weak pull-up resistors on port C except
                            //    RC0 and RC1 to be used as I2C SCL and SDA
    TRISA  = 0b00110000;    // Set RA4 and RA5 as inputs
    ANSELA = 0b00110000;    // Set RA4 and RA5 to analog
    TRISB  = 0b00110000;    // Set RB6 and RB7 as inputs
    ANSELB = 0b11000000;    // Set RB6 and RB7 as analog
    TRISC  = 0b11111011;    // Set RC0, RC1, RC3, RC4, RC5, RC6, and RC7 as inputs
    ANSELC = 0b11111000;    // Set RC3, RC4, RC5, RC6, and RC7 as analog
#ifdef WRONG_WAY_TO_DO_PPS
    TX2CKPPS   = 0b01100;   // Use RB4 for TX2
    RX2DTPPS   = 0b01110;   // Use RB6 for RX2
    SSP1CLKPPS = 0b10000;   // Use RC0 as SCL
    SSP1DATPPS = 0b10001;   // Use RC1 as SDA
#else
    RB4PPS     = 0x11;      // Assign TX2 output  to RB4
    RX2DTPPS   = 0x0E;      // Assign RB6         to RX2 input
    RC0PPS     = 0x15;      // Assign SCL1 output to RC0
    SSP1CLKPPS = 0x10;      // Assign RC0         to SCL1 input
    RC1PPS     = 0x16;      // Assign SDA1 output to RC1
    SSP1DATPPS = 0x11;      // Assign RC1         to SDA1 input
#endif
    SSP1CON1 = 0b00100110;  // SSPEN enabled, WCOL no collision, SSPOV no overflow,
                            // CKP low hold, SSPM I2C slave 7-bit

    SSP1CON2 = 0b00000000;  // ACKSTAT received, RCEN disabled, RSEN disabled, 
                            // ACKEN disabled, ACKDT acknowledge, SEN disabled, 
                            // GCEN disabled, PEN disabled

    SSP1CON3 = 0b00000000;  // BOEN disabled, AHEN disabled, SBCDE disabled, 
                            // SDAHT 100 ns hold, ACKTIM ackseq, DHEN disabled, 
                            // PCIE disabled, SCIE disabled

    SSP1STAT = 0x00;
    SSP1BUF  = 0x00;
    SSP1MSK  = 0xff;
    SSP1ADD  = I2C_SLAVE_ADDR << 1;
    PIR3bits.SSP1IF = 0;    // Clear the SSP Interrupt flag
    PIE3bits.SSP1IE = 1;    // Enable SSP Interrupts
    INTCONbits.GIE = 1;     // Enable global interrupts
    INTCONbits.PEIE = 1;    // Enable peripheral interrupts
    /*
     * Embedded code never returns from main
     */
    for(;;)
    {

    }
}
```

The PPS is setup correctly but I do not know if the I2C initialization code is right.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll give that PPS configuration a try, but I now I understand that my PPS configuration couldn't have worked because the I2C outputs weren't going anywhere, which would explain why the master wasn't getting an ACK back from the PIC.

Comment: I just tried those changes to the PPS configuration and my I2C interface is working now.  Thanks again.